# Netlify Build Fails with "ReferenceError: self is not defined" in Next.js App Using browser-image-resizer which clearly runs on the server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm encountering a build error when deploying my Next.js application to Netlify. The build process fails with the error message "ReferenceError: self is not defined." The error seems to be related to the browser-image-resizer library used in my SingleImageUploadInput component.

Here's the relevant part of the component where browser-image-resizer is imported and used:

```
'use client';

import "./forminput.css";
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { readAndCompressImage } from 'browser-image-resizer';


const SingleImageUploadInput = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDragOver, setIsDragOver] = useState(false);
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(false);
    const [imageName, setImageName] = useState('');
    const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState('');
    const fileInputRef = useRef();
// ... Component code using readAndCompressImage
```

i also tried importing the readAndCompressImage in the useEffect after the page has loaded but it also gives and error and somehow breaks my styling

below is what i tried

```
const SingleImageUploadInput = ({ children }) => {
    const [readAndCompressImage, setReadAndCompressImage] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const { readAndCompressImage } = require('browser-image-resizer');
        setReadAndCompressImage(() => readAndCompressImage);
    }, []);
```

and i get the error in the chrome console

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: screen_capture_injected
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:294:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:157:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:82:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:110:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:440:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:126:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:142:11)
```

i clearly used `use client` to let next know that this code is to be run on the client but it doesnt solve the issue.

how can i solve this issue?